# SQL SqlDataAdapter with Parameters returning "reference not set"

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I'm trying to use a `SELECT` query with `SqlDataAdapter` to fill a dataset, the problem is occurring in this `parameters.add` line. The `SqlConnection` is OK.

```
Dim dt As New DataSet()

Using adapter As New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * from TAB_Movimentos WHERE Banco = @Banco", New SqlConnection(MontaStringConexaoSQLServer()))
    adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@Banco", SqlDbType.Int)
    adapter.Fill(dt)
End Using
```

Returning:

> Referência de objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto." (BR)
>
> Object reference not set to an instance of an object." (EN)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed; you've set a SELECT query but that doesn't mean that the DataAdapter's *UpdateCommand* is set to anything

```
        Dim dt As New DataTable()
        Using adapter As New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * from TAB_Movimentos WHERE Banco = @Banco", New SqlConnection(MontaStringConexaoSQLServer()))
            adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@Banco", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 1234
            adapter.Fill(dt)
        End Using
```

You don't need to use a DataSet (a collection of datatables) - a DataAdapter knows how to fill a DataTable. Using a dataset for this is like using an array of strings when all you really want is a single string

You also forgot to give the parameter a value. I gave it 1234

Comment: Nice! It worked... One more question, I got confuse about DataSet, I understood your explain but I tried to googled it without success...

Comment: You can think of a DataTable as a thing which has zero or more rows. You could also think of a DataSet as a thing that has zero or more DataTables.
A DataAdapter can "fill" and empty DataTable, but it can also fill an empty DataSet (in which case you get a DataSet with a single DataTable containing your rows).
If you just have a single table, fill a DataTable.

Comment: A `DataSet` is like an array of `DataTable`s and is the conceptual equivalent of an entire database. A `DataTable` is like an array of `DataRow`s and is the equivalent of a single DB table. If you want a DataTable, use a DataTable, not a DataSet. After all, if you want a single string you write `Dim s as String = "Hello World"`, you don't write `Dim s(100) as New String` `s(0) = "Hello World"`. No-one make an array of 100 strings if all they want is a string. You'll nearly never need to use a DataSet if you only user use a DataAdapter, so if nothing else, just remember "DataTable, not DataSet"